# How I can get the last query statement executed on R2DBC to log with a WebFilter?

Tags: spring-webflux, r2dbc-postgresql

I have seen that inside the WebFilter (Using Spring Webflux) we have the access to the Application Context, so do you know the way to get the Last Query Executed?
to log in my custom Logger.

I know we can use this to see the logs.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.r2dbc=DEBUG
```

But I'm looking the way to handle it, in a different way.